# How can I interact with form inputs in the Fancybox3 caption block?

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox, fancybox-3

I'm using the custom templating to add input fields for a form in the caption region:

```
..fancybox({
  caption: function (instance, item) {
    return "FORM CONTAINING AN INPUT FIELD";
  }
}
```

The fields display nicely, but I can't actually click any of the form elements.  Fancybox just steals the input for interacting with the image.  Is there a way to make the stuff in the div.fancybox-caption-wrap be able to handle their own input and keep the image above it?  Basically, just to make it work like the div.fancybox-controls which allows interactivity (and acts as a top for the image).

I tried searching for options on the documentation page but nothing seemed to fit or work.  The "touch" event seemed like it might steal events, but on/off made no difference.  Disabling "closeClickOutside" also doesn't help.  Interacting with form elements worked with Fancybox2 without any extra steps.  What else can I try?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I need to have a button in the image caption, and it stopped working with fancybox3. Thanks.

Comment: It is quite annoying that there seems to be no solution to this

Comment: I ended up needing to just change tactic.  Very frustrating!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By default all Pointer events are disabled in caption area.

To enable input text or any other html fields inside fancybox caption box
add this css rule.

```
.fancybox-caption-wrap {
    pointer-events: all;
}
```

I am using fancybox-3.1.20 with .fancybox-custom-layout

here is my working code.

```
            caption: function (instance, item) {
                var caption = $(this).data('caption') || '';

                if (item.type === 'image') {
                    caption = '(<span data-fancybox-index></span>/<span data-fancybox-count></span>)' + '<br />' + (caption.length ? caption + '<br />' : '') +
                    '<input type="text" value="comment">' +
                    $('#comments_panel').html()
                    ;
                }
                return caption;
            }
```

Checkout the screenshot of my fancybox image comments panel inside caption area.

[image]

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this sooner Rajiv!  That simple CSS rule did the trick.  So annoying I didn't see it sooner.  Thanks for your help!